# CakePHP unexpected t_string on a blank line

Tags: php, cakephp

I am experiencing this error on a CakePHP website:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home3/website/public_html/app/controllers/users_controller.php on line 1010

The thing is there is no code/comment/anything on that line, and the website was working up until an hour ago.

The nearest code to line 1010 is

```
$user['User']['facebook_locale'] = $facebook->locale;
```

This error is affecting any page I try and visit, eg domain.com, domain.com/sub/page

Here is the code around the 1010 line mark

```
$user['User']['facebook_locale'] = $facebook->locale; (line 1007)
// Line 1008
// Line 1009
// Line 1010
$this->User->save($user, false); // Line 1011
```

I inherited this website so the blank lines were there already.

Comment: Is that line before or after 1010?  Make sure all curly braces open and close correctly and that you're not missing a semi-colon somewhere.

Comment: Why would PHP say the error is line 1010 when there is no code?

Comment: what's the full debug log? Is there something wrong in your AppController?

Comment: I don't know , I am new to Cake. How do I know if something is wrong in AppController?